# Modelagem de dados com pessoas de perfis diferentes

Tags: banco-de-dados, modelagem

Preciso criar um sistema onde pessoas podem exercer papéis diferentes. (ex. Podem ser docentes, discentes e servidor).
As principais informações são:

Perfil do docente: nome, endereço, email, área de atuação, disciplina, etc.
Perfil do discente: nome, endereço, email, Matrícula, Curso, País, etc
Perfil do servidor: nome, endereço, email, lotação, setor, cargo, nível, etc.

A pergunta é: Qual a melhor forma de modelar um banco com essas tabelas?

Comment: Um `discente` pode ser também `docente`?

Comment: Não entendo porque as pessoas acham que o fato da pessoa desempenhar um papel diferente ela deva ser outra pessoa. Pessoa é pessoa, o papel que ela tem é algo acessório. É o mesmo que: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/191832/101 ou  http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/54177/101 ou http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/80948/101

Comment: Um discente não pode ser docente. Porém, quem foi discente um dia poderá via a ser docente, ou servidor.
Não é apenas desempenhar papéis diferentes. Existem muitos dados referentes a cada perfil que não inseri na pergunta pra não deixar muito grande.
Ex. Curso e matrícula são dados exclusivos do Discente.
Lotação, cargo, nível são dados exclusivos do servidor.
Área de atuação e disciplina são dados exclusivos do docente.

Comment: Neste caso, veja a resposta do @Maycon-Pires que é praticamente o que eu ia dizer: uma unica tabela para pessoas e uma tabela para cada papel em que possam atuar, ligadas por pares de chave primária/estrangeira.

Comment: Obrigado, @ReneFreak.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você tem a seguinte opção:

1- Crie uma tabela Pessoa com um Chave Primária ID. Nessa tabela você possuirá todos os dados comuns das pessoas (Docente e Discente).

2- Crie uma tabela Docente que possua como chave Estrangeira (FK) o Id da pessoa. E acrescente apenas os dados do docente.

3- Crie uma tabela Discente que possua como chave Estrangeira (FK) o Id da pessoa. E acrescente apenas os dados do discente.

Isto é conhecido como especialização.

Abraço!

Comment: Caro @Maycon Pires, obrigado pela resposta. Abraço.

Comment: @RenatoPaiva modelar bem o banco de dados facilita muito no momento de fazer relatórios e criar uma database dimensional. Abc sucesso!