# Superclasse pode se tornar subclasse?

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, herança

Tenho as classes `Versao`, que uma versão geral, `VersaoFirmware` e `VersaoSoftware`. Na prática o usuário pode adicionar uma ou mais versões para um equipamento. Porém, no primeiro momento, ainda não se sabe qual o tipo de versão. Então vou adicionando as versões com `new Versao()`. Quando ele terminar de adicionar as versões, ele deve selecionar qual é o tipo das versões, `VersaoFirmware` ou `VersaoSoftware`.

#### O que eu tentei:

De cara, vi o esquema e pensei: "Trata-se claramente de um caso de herança. Tenho uma superclasse `Versao` que tem as propriedades comuns a todos os tipos de versão. E tenho as subclasses `VersaoFirmware` e `VersaoSoftware` que herdam da superclasse, pois elas têm tudo que a `Versao` tem, mais um ou outro método diferente.".

```
class Versao {
    private int id;
    private String name;

    public Versao() {}
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

```
class VersaoFirmware extends Versao {
    private String outraCoisa;

    public VersaoFirmware() {}
    public String fazOutraCoisa() {
        return outraCoisa;
    }
}
```

```
class VersaoSoftware extends Versao {
    private String outraCoisa;

    public VersaoSoftware () {}
    public String fazOutraCoisa() {
        return outraCoisa;
    }
}
```

Porém, deparei-me com o seguinte problema: depois que o usuário selecionar o tipo da versão, como transformo a versão geral, para a versão específica? Devo criar novas instâncias de cada tipo e passar os atributos manualmente?
Por exemplo:

```
Versao versao = new Versao();
versao.setName("Versao");

VersaoSoftware versaoSoft = new VersaoSoftware();
versaoSoft.setName(versao.getName());
versaoSoft.setId(versao.getId()); // ....
```

Mas e se `Versao` tiver 50 propriedades, vou ter que passar todas manualmente? E assim também me parece sem sentido o uso de herança.

Complementando o título da pergunta, tentei inverter a hierarquia das classes, resolveu o problema, mas fica totalmente sem sentido deixar exposto métodos específicos para a versão geral.

Li a respeito sobre [Cópia de Construtor](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=12), que resumidamente cria uma subclasse a partir de uma superclasse. Mas da mesma maneira, teria que passar todos as propriedades manualmente.

Como faço para modelar esse sistema? Há alguma outra estratégia para resolver este problema?

Comment: Fiz uma pergunta parecido no SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27134754/subclass-instance-to-superclass. Apesar de eu aceitar a resposta, fiz essa pergunta aqui com mais detalhes, pra ver se é correta essa estratégia.

Comment: Use um método reflexivo para copiar as propriedades. Uma das classes mais conhecidas é a [`BeanUtils.copyProperties`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/apidocs/org/apache/commons/beanutils/BeanUtils.html)

Comment: Peça pro usuário informar **antes** o tipo da versão; então você saberá o tipo de objeto a instanciar antes de o usuário começar a entrar com os detalhes de cada versão. Se cada tipo de versão tem informações específicas, nem faz sentido o usuário informar o tipo das versões depois de informar as próprias versões.

Comment: @Caffé Concordo com você. Mas sabe como é: "O chefe pediu". Aí nosso maior trabalho é tentar convencer o chefe que essa não é a melhor maneira. Caso não consiga, o programador que se vire.

Comment: @Earendul Você também pode resolver com mecânica de aplicativo (manter uma lista de estrutura de dados e criar os objetos de negócio quando já tiver as informações mínimas necessárias disponíveis), sem corromper a modelagem por uma necessidade muito específica de usabilidade.

Comment: Relacionado: ["É correto dar maior preferência a composição do que herança?"](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/11378/215) Eu diria que esse é um caso onde se justifica abrir mão da herança, ainda que a sintaxe da linguagem não ajude (se você quer um único objeto com todas as propriedades relevantes, alguma coisa você vai ter que fazer à mão). A propósito, você precisa mesmo criar o objeto da classe antes mesmo do usuário terminar de preencher os campos na tela? Não dá pra fazer isso no final? E o que acontece se o usuário escolher o tipo errado, ele vai ter que cancelar tudo e começar de novo?

Comment: @mgibsonbr Não precisa, tanto que já mudei o modo, primeiro o usuário insere os dados e seleciona o tipo, só então ele pode adicionar as versões daquele tipo. Porém, ainda fico na dúvida num caso em que não poderia selecionar o tipo antes.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Bom, o conceito de herança é um pouco mal compreendido apesar de simples. Herança em O.O. não é apenas reutilizar código (diferente do que muitos costumam dizer), isso é apenas uma consequência. Herança deve ser aplicada quando uma classe claramente se tratar de uma extensão de outra classe.

Na sua situação, você poderia não utilizar herança, pois pelo que percebo, se a ideia é apenas reutilizar atributos (e não comportamentos), você poderia optar pela composição:

```
public class DadosVersao {
   private Tipo atributoA;
   private Tipo atributoB;
}

public class VersaoSoftware {
   private DadosVersao atributos = new DadosVersao();
}

public class VersaoHardware {
   private DadosVersao atributos = new DadosVersao();
}
```

Você poderia receber os atributos no construtor das classes.

Mas se realmente quer utilizar herança, creio que faça sentido sua classe Versao ser abstrata, pois sozinha não faz sentido existir.

```
public abstract class Versao {
...
}
```

Se quiser criar um esteriótipo para a versão, basta criar um método abstrato que obrigue as classes filhas a implementarem:

```
public abstract class Versao {
   public abstract String getTipo();
}

public class VersaoSoftware extends Versao {

   @Override
   public String getTipo() {
       return "software";
   }

}
```

E, ainda, se for popular dados da classe filha com atributos da mãe, simples:

```
public class VersaoSoftware extends Versao {

   public VersaoSoftware(Atributo atributoEspecificoSoftware, Atributo atributoVersao) {
      this.atributoEspecificoSoftware = atributoEspecificoSoftware;
      super.setAtributoVersao(atributoVersao); //pode usar um atributo protected diretamente ou, ainda, não precisa do super se for o setter publico ;P
   }

   @Override
   public String getTipo() {
       return "software";
   }

}
```

Existem muitas opções para isso, mas o ideal é utilizar herança quando fazer sentido a **especialização** da classe no aspecto comportamental e não apenas no característico.

Answer (score 2):

Acho que você já achou a solução. A melhor maneira, e uma prática bem conceituada de arquitetura, é a cópia de construtor. Algo como:

```
 Versao versao = new Versao();
 versao.setName("Versao");

 VersaoSoftware versaoSoft = new VersaoSoftware(versao);
 VersaoFirmware versaoFirm = new VersaoFirmware(versao);
```

Na classe base, você faria um função que seria chamada pelas funções construtores:

```
 public Clone(Versao origem)
 {
       this.prop1 = origem.prop1;
       this.prop2 = origem.prop2; // etc...
 }
```

Isso faz com que você possa alterar a classe base sem afetar os outros construtores, afinal eles iriam chamar sempre a mesma função não importa em que versão do software.

Você poderia seguir essa mesma arquitetura para eventuais mudanças futuras nas suas classes filhas (ou filhas estendendo as filhas). Assim você não precisa se preocupar em setar as propriedades da classe mãe nas classes filhas, o que seria repetição perigosa de código se algum dia alguém estender a classe mãe e esquecer de olhar para todas as filhas.

Comment: No meu caso acho que é isso mesmo. Mas fiquei pensando, "e se eu tivesse muuuitas propriedades? Teria que passar todas manualmente? Será que não existe uma solução melhor para isso?" Mas pelo jeito esse é a melhor maneira mesmo.

Comment: @Earendul acho que você tem razão na maioria das propriedades, mas nem todas elas são triviais. As vezes você precisa fazer alguma operação para setar cada uma delas, etc. Somente uma coisa que esqueci de falar e logo complemento minha resposta: a `Clone` deve ser chamada sempre como `base.Clone(origem);` em todos os construtores das classes filhas (talvez em um método `Clone` também). É importante que não hava um `override` da classe mãe inicial por uma classe mãe intermediária, deve ter uma sequência de chamados.

Answer (score 2):

### Problema

Creio que você esteja pensando de maneira errada (você deveria escrever para nós o seu requisíto e não o que você já pensou). Vou tentar me focar na descrição do seu problema. Indo por partes, você disse que:

- Tem um **Equipamento**
- Na prática o usuário pode adicionar **uma ou mais** versões para um **equipamento**
- *Quando ele terminar de adicionar as versões, ele deve selecionar qual é o tipo das versões, VersaoFirmware ou VersaoSoftware* (esta daqui ficou confusa, afinal um **equipamento tem N versões** ou **equipamento tem 1 Versão**?. Usei o pior cenário, sendo 1 equipamento para N versão, se necessário, você adapta depois)

**Veja seu diagrama**:

[image: diagrama]

**Sendo**:

- 1 Versão tem 1 TipoVersao (usei enum para simplificar, mas você pode trocar por uma entidade de mais alto nível)
- 1 Versão tem N PropriedadesVersao

### Saída que eu imagino que você queira

[image: saida esperada]

### Classes para teste

```
public class Equipamento {
    public String nome;
    public List<Versao> versoes = new ArrayList<Versao>();
}

public class Versao {
    public TipoVersao tipoVersao;
    public List<PropriedadeVersao> propriedadesVersao = new ArrayList<PropriedadeVersao>();
}

public enum TipoVersao {
    HARDWARE, SOFTWARE
}

public class PropriedadeVersao {
    public String nome;
    public String valor;
}
```

Trecho de amostra com as classes

```
    Equipamento equipamento = new Equipamento();
    equipamento.nome = "TV Samsung";

    // VERSAO DE HARDWARE

    Versao versaoHardware = new Versao();
    versaoHardware.tipoVersao = TipoVersao.HARDWARE;

    PropriedadeVersao propriedadeVersaoChipset = new PropriedadeVersao();
    propriedadeVersaoChipset.nome = "Chipset";
    propriedadeVersaoChipset.valor = "111.1";
    versaoHardware.propriedadesVersao.add(propriedadeVersaoChipset);

    PropriedadeVersao propriedadeVersaoAquecimentoMaximo = new PropriedadeVersao();
    propriedadeVersaoAquecimentoMaximo.nome = "Aquecimento Maximo";
    propriedadeVersaoAquecimentoMaximo.valor = "20º";
    versaoHardware.propriedadesVersao.add(propriedadeVersaoAquecimentoMaximo);

    equipamento.versoes.add(versaoHardware);

    // VERSAO DE SOFTWARE       

    Versao versaoSoftware = new Versao();
    versaoSoftware.tipoVersao = TipoVersao.SOFTWARE;

    PropriedadeVersao propriedadeVersaoFabricante = new PropriedadeVersao();
    propriedadeVersaoFabricante.nome = "Fabricante";
    propriedadeVersaoFabricante.valor = "Microsoft";
    versaoSoftware.propriedadesVersao.add(propriedadeVersaoFabricante);

    equipamento.versoes.add(versaoSoftware);

    // IMPRIME DADOS

    System.out.println("Equipamento: " + equipamento.nome);

    for (Versao versao : equipamento.versoes) {
        System.out.println("- Versao: " + versao.tipoVersao.toString());            
        for (PropriedadeVersao propriedadeVersao : versao.propriedadesVersao) {
            System.out.println("-- " + propriedadeVersao.nome + " = " + propriedadeVersao.valor);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Utilize composição:

```java
// coisas comuns, ainda não definiu se firmware/software
Versao versao = new Versao(1, "0.0.1");
// se firmware...
VersaoFirmware firmware = new VersaoFirmware(versao, "Firmware");
// se software...
VersaoSoftware software = new VersaoSoftware(versao, "software");
```

Tendo como superclasse:

```java
abstract class PossuiVersao {
  final Versao versao;
  PossuiVersao(Versao versao) {
    this.versao = versao;
  }
  // métodos delegam para Versao, 
  // assim PossuiVersao comporta-se como Versao.
  public int getId() {
    return versao.getId();
  }
  public String getName() {
    return versao.getName();
  }
}
```

E as subclasses:

```java
class VersaoFirmware extends PossuiVersao {
  final String coisaFirmware;
  VersaoFirmware(Versao versao, String coisaFirmware) {
    super(versao);
    this.coisaFirmware = coisaFirmware;
  }
  void somenteFirmware() {
    // comportamento específico firmware
  }
}

class VersaoSoftware extends PossuiVersao {
  final String coisaSoftware;
  VersaoSoftware(Versao versao, String coisaSoftware) {
    super(versao);
    this.coisaSoftware = coisaSoftware;
  }
  void somenteSoftware() {
    // comportamento específico software
  }
}
```