# Saber qual classe filha a classe pai aponta

Tags: c++, orientação-a-objetos, classes, herança

Vim do java e estou com uma dúvida sobre o polimorfismo em C++.

Dado essas classes:

```
class Empresa{
vector<Pessoa> pessoas;
int empregados;
addPessoa(Pessoa* p)
}

class Pessoa {
...
};


class Empregado:public Pessoa{
...
}

class Dono:public Pessoa{
...
}

e a função:

addPessoa(Pessoa* p){
pessoas.push_back(*p);
if(...) // pessoa é um empregado
empregados++;
}
```

Não estou conseguindo implementar esse `if`.

Comment: Não conheço muito C++, mas sei que a maioria das soluções nesse sentido se baseiam no uso do `dynamic_cast`. Em outras palavras, você tentaria transformar `p` num novo objeto da classe `Empregado` e testaria se o ponteiro não é nulo.

Comment: O que é funcionário? Isso é um conceito representado no código? Só estou vendo "empregado". É a mesma coisa?

Comment: Polimorfismo não é usar `if`. A ideia do polimorfismo é você simplesmente fazer a chamada de uma função e a implementação correta ser chamada baseada no tipo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A solução para isso é igual ao Java, se a função deve adicionar um `Empregado` então faça a função receber isso e não a classe geral. Assim como para os outros cargos.

```
addEmpregado(Empregado* p) {
    pessoas.push_back(*p);
    funcionarios++;
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/OOP/Polymorphism2.cpp).

Quem vai chamar a função sabe que tipo de objeto é, então é ela que deve decidir o que chamar.

Não vou entrar no mérito que esta herança talvez não seja adequada. Há muito [abuso de herança](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/11378/101).

Comment: muito bom o 'debate' no link. Obrigado.