# Problema de import ao compilar classes em pacotes diferentes

Tags: java, importação, packages

Estou com um problema de `import` de um *package* que eu criei em Java, a árvore de diretório do projeto é essa:

```
.
├── CsvFiles
│   ├── 01
│   ├── 01.zip
│   ├── ALPOO_GRADUACAO_2018.csv
│   ├── ALPOO_GRADUACAO_2019.csv
│   ├── ALPOO_POS_GRADUACAO_2019.csv
│   ├── alunos.csv
│   ├── cursos.csv
│   └── LPOO_GRADUACAO_2019.csv
├── LICENSE
└── src
    ├── entidades
    │   ├── Aluno.class
    │   ├── Aluno.java
    │   ├── Curso.class
    │   ├── Curso.java
    │   ├── Nota.class
    │   ├── Nota.java
    │   ├── Rendimento.class
    │   └── Rendimento.java
    ├── io_handle
    │   ├── handleCSV.java
    │   ├── Menu.class
    │   └── Menu.java
    └── tests
        ├── ALPOO_GRADUACAO_2019.csv
        ├── test.class
        └── test.java
```

Estou criando um *package* por diretório, por exemplo dentro de `entidades`, todos os arquivos `.java` tem em sua primeira linha o código:

```
package entidades;
```

No arquivo `handleCSV.java`, importo algumas classes do package `entidades`, e declaro seu *package* com o seguinte código:

```
package io_handle;

import entidades.Nota;
import entidades.Aluno;
```

Porém quando compilo o `Nota.java`, recebo o erro:

```
╰──➤  javac Nota.java 
Nota.java:3: error: cannot find symbol
import entidades.Aluno;
                ^
  symbol:   class Aluno
  location: package entidades
Nota.java:9: error: cannot find symbol
public class Nota extends Aluno {
                          ^
  symbol: class Aluno
2 errors
```

E consequentemente quando compilo `handleCSV.java` recebo o erro:

```
╰──➤  javac handleCSV.java 
handleCSV.java:21: error: package entidades does not exist
import entidades.Nota;
                ^
handleCSV.java:22: error: package entidades does not exist
import entidades.Aluno;
                ^
handleCSV.java:23: error: package entidades does not exist

...

21 errors
```

Porém quando compilo todos os arquivos juntos com o comando:

```
╰──➤  javac Aluno.java Curso.java Nota.java Rendimento.java
```

Não recebo erro algum. Porém o erro na compilação de `handleCSV.java` continua.

Sobre os arquivos em si, `Curso.java`, `Aluno.Java`, `Rendimento.java`, `handleCSV.java` e `Menu.java` estão iniciados da seguinte forma:

```
public class [Nome da classe] {
...
}
```

Já `Nota.java` está iniciada da seguinte forma:

```
public class Nota extends Aluno {
...
}
```

Comment: O que é isso, Maven? O `src` é pra ficar fora do nome do pacote. Pode até ter achado de algum jeito resolvendo assim, mas está errado. Tem que resolver o erro que deu quando não usava o `src`, não sei se é configuração de classpath ou o quê.

Comment: Problema XY. Edite a pergunta colocando o problema original. Votei para fechar como não clara.

Comment: Poderia verificar se a classe Aluno está sendo declarada como public?
no caso: public class Aluno {<Conteudo-da-classe>} Pois caso não esteja, realmente a referencia da classe não vai ser capturada pelo compilador.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compilar os arquivos manualmente pode ser um bom aprendizado para entender como as coisas funcionam, mas na prática é melhor usar ferramentas que automatizam isso para você, como o [Maven](https://maven.apache.org/), [Gradle](https://gradle.org/), entre [outros](https://stackshare.io/java-build-tools). Dito isso, vamos ver como resolver o seu caso.

---

Pelas linhas de comando indicadas, parece que você está entrando em cada pasta separadamente. Em vez disso, vá no diretório raiz do projeto e compile tudo de uma vez:

```
javac -d target/ -sourcepath src/ src/entidades/*java src/io_handle/*java
```

Ou, se estiver usando Linux:

```
javac -d target/ -sourcepath src/ $(find src -name "*.java")
```

Ao compilar `Nota` separadamente, ele não vai encontrar a classe `Aluno` porque ela ainda não foi compilada. Por isso "funcionou" quando você compilou `Aluno` antes. Mas ao compilar `handleCSV`, como você está na pasta `io_handle`, ele irá procurar pela pasta `entidades` dentro de `io_handle` para resolver os `import`'s.

---

Para evitar essa confusão, basta compilar a partir da raiz do projeto, e aí todas as classes serão procuradas a partir da pasta indicada pela opção `sourcepath`.

Ou seja, eu estou na raiz do projeto e indiquei `-sourcepath src/`, então estou indicando que qualquer classe será buscada a partir de `src` (qualquer classe que esteja no pacote `entidades` será buscada na pasta `src/entidades`, o mesmo vale para o pacote `io_handle` e qualquer outro pacote).

Depois você passa a lista de arquivos (que pode ser manualmente, como na primeira opção, ou usando o comando `find`, caso esteja no Linux, que já busca todos os arquivos `.java` que estão na pasta `src`).

Também usei a opção `-d` para indicar o diretório no qual serão colocados os arquivos `.class`. Se eu não fizer isso, o compilador cria o `.class` no mesmo diretório em que estão os `.java`. No caso, chamei de `target` (mas também há o costume/convenção de chamar de `bin` ou `build`). Minha opinião pessoal é que assim fica mais organizado, pois você não mistura os fontes com os arquivos compilados (ferramentas como o Maven fazem isso por padrão).

---

Não diretamente relacionado, mas procure seguir as [convenções de nomenclatura da linguagem](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-namingconventions.html): classes começam com letra maiúscula (`HandleCSV` em vez de `handleCSV`).

Outro ponto é que não parece fazer muito sentido `Nota` ser uma subclasse de `Aluno`. Uma nota não é uma especialização do aluno, na verdade um aluno pode ter várias notas (é um caso em que [composição é mais adequada que herança](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/11378/112052)). Claro que depende dos seus requisitos, mas não consigo imaginar uma situação em que essa herança específica faça sentido.